# How can I pause an MP3 file using C#?

Tags: c#, audio

I have this class I found in a website:

```
class MP3Handler
{
    private string _command;
    private bool isOpen;
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]

    private static extern long mciSendString(string strCommand, StringBuilder strReturn, int iReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback);

    public void Close()
    {
        _command = "close MediaFile";
        mciSendString(_command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        isOpen = false;
    }

    public void Open(string sFileName)
    {
        _command = "open \"" + sFileName + "\" type mpegvideo alias MediaFile";
        mciSendString(_command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        isOpen = true;
    }

    public void Play(bool loop)
    {
        if (isOpen)
        {
            _command = "play MediaFile";
            if (loop)
                _command += " REPEAT";
            mciSendString(_command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
}
```

Is has the methods for STOP and PLAY. I was wondering if anyone is familiar with the winmm.dll library. How can I pause the song as it's playing and then continue from where it was paused?

Comment: A project that does play, pause, etc., using winmm.dll: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Audio_Player__with_Winmm.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MP3Example.aspx) CodeProject article contains a class which handles may of the functions of the winmm.dll library, including pause, and may be helpful for this and in the future.

The basic code, however, is:

```
    _command = "pause MediaFile";
    mciSendString(_command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the [Multimedia Command Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712587(VS.85).aspx).

I see the [pause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712828(VS.85).aspx) and [resume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713233(VS.85).aspx) commands are included:

> The **pause** command pauses playing or
>   recording. Most drivers retain the
>   current position and eventually resume
>   playback or recording at this
>   position. CD audio, digital-video,
>   MIDI sequencer, VCR, videodisc, and
>   waveform-audio devices recognize this
>   command.
>
> The **resume** command continues playing
>   or recording on a device that has been
>   paused using the pause command.
>   Digital-video, VCR, and waveform-audio
>   devices recognize this command.
>   Although CD audio, MIDI sequencer, and
>   videodisc devices also recognize this
>   command, the MCICDA, MCISEQ, and
>   MCIPIONR device drivers do not support
>   it.

So I guess you would have:

```
bool isPaused = false;

public void Pause() {
    if (isOpen && !isPaused) {
        _command = "pause MediaFile";
        mciSendString(_command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        isPaused = true;
    }
}

public void Resume() {
    if (isOpen && isPaused) {
        _command = "resume MediaFile";
        mciSendString(_command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        isPaused = false;
    }
}
```