# Pause/Play button in vb 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, button

I am new to stackoverflow and the programming world. I have a basic program i'm making that will play a song in the background.

I already have that part working, it auto starts a launch of program.

However, I would like to have a button that pauses, then resumes the audio.

(I am trying to avoid making it a media player and using the media player control) Song was add as a resource.

My.Computer.Audio.Stop (works to stop it.)

But how can I implement the pause,resume? by adding a boolean or something?

(I would like pause and resume feature to be within the same button)

Comment: Wpf or Winforms. and are you wanting to start where you left off or just restart the audio

Comment: @Mark Hall

I know that i wont be able to pause resume using the same method, but still i am trying to stay away from system windows media player. Is it possible t use a timer method?


(if there is no other way possible i will resort to wmp, but what if a computer does not have windows media player? will the function still work?)

Edit: And: start where the audio left off.

Comment: The answer that I started to give was to use System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer but is is a WPF class, I do not beleive that it is dependent on Windows Media player but I am looking

Comment: So i would have to add both, "user control (wpf)" and windows media player?... I will be using .wav files but just need one button to resume and pause.

Comment: It is built into the framework. I do not see where it is dependent on the Windows Media Player. Though the documentation on how to use it is very sparse in MSDN. As far as your one button Resume and Pause use a boolean variable to determine which function to process. To answer my earlier question **is your app a Winform or WPF app?**

Comment: to add some additional information. It looks like accorded to this [Micosoft.Connect Case](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/374363/system-windows-media-mediaplayer-only-plays-sounds-once-in-windows-xp) there is a link between System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer and Windows System Media Player. So you will not be able to depend on it being on all machines since Microsoft had to make the N versions which do not have it avialable in Europe.

Comment: thanks for the info and my application is in a winForm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used reflector and the internal implementation of Audio.Play uses the SoundPlayer:

```
Public Sub Play(ByVal location As String, ByVal playMode As AudioPlayMode)
    Me.ValidateAudioPlayModeEnum(playMode, "playMode")
    Dim sound As New SoundPlayer(Me.ValidateFilename(location))
    Me.Play(sound, playMode)
End Sub
```

So unless you make your own or derive from the SoundPlayer class your options appear to be quite limited (ref Audio methods dont have pause or resume: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cf1shcah(v=vs.90).aspx).

May I suggest giving up on this class, it doesn't support the pause/resume methods you want. Instead focus your time on [How can I pause an MP3 file using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704729/how-can-i-pause-an-mp3-file-using-c) - the [CodeProject Playing MP3s using MCI](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MP3Example.aspx) or alternatively look into methods like this: http://alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx

Comment: Okay i will play around a bit thank you for th info. I'll be back on tonight with conclusion on how i did this

Comment: Decided to just use the .play and .stop function.